# How to fix drag and drop quiz?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I need help with my drag and drop quiz that works for me.

I have two mistakes in it. The first one is that the text that drags to the box won't stay there for me and the second mistake is that it doesn't count down my score when I move it to the right box where it should belong, so nothing happens.

I need to consult with the team because I don't know what a team is. I apologize in retrospect that it is in Czech and not in English, but I didn't want to rewrite it anymore.

Thank you for your help.

```js
var score = 0;
var doprava = ['Doprava'];
var zdravotnictvi = ['Zdravotnictví'];
var autprumysl = ['Automobilový průmysl'];
var finance = ['Finance']
var scoreElement = document.querySelector(".score");

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  if (ev.target.doprava == 'textBox3' && doprava.indexOf(data) != -1) {
    score++;
    scoreElement.innerHTML = score.toString() + "/4";
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
  if (ev.target.zdravotnictvi == 'textBox2' && zdravotnictvi.indexOf(data) != -1) {
    score++;
    scoreElement.innerHTML = score.toString() + "/4";
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
  if (ev.target.finance == 'textBox4' && finance.indexOf(data) != -1) {
    score++;
    scoreElement.innerHTML = score.toString() + "/4";
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
  if (ev.target.autprumysl == 'textBox1' && autprumysl.indexOf(data) != -1) {
    score++;
    scoreElement.innerHTML = score.toString() + "/4";
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="module">
  <br>
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='modules/OdvetviTechnologie/Automobil.Prumysl.png') }}" width="320" height="200" />
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='modules/OdvetviTechnologie/Zdravotnictvi.png') }}" width="320" height="200" />
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='modules/OdvetviTechnologie/Doprava.png') }}" width="320" height="200" />
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='modules/OdvetviTechnologie/Finance.png') }}" width="320" height="200" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="textBox1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="textBox2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="textBox3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="textBox4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="drag">
    <span class="span" id="doprava" draggable="true" ondragover="drag(event)">Doprava</span>
    <span class="span" id="zdravotnictvi" draggable="true" ondragover="drag(event)">Zdravotnictví</span>
    <span class="span" id="autprumysl" draggable="true" ondragover="drag(event)">Automobilový průmysl</span>
    <span class="span" id="finance" draggable="true" ondragover="drag(event)">Finance</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p style="font-size:20px; text-align: center;" class="score">0/0</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See updated Snippet below:

```js
var score = 0;
var scoreElement = document.querySelector(".score");

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  if (data == ev.target.getAttribute("data-id")) {
    score++;
    scoreElement.innerHTML = score.toString() + "/4";
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
}
```

```css
#textBox1, #textBox2, #textBox3, #textBox4 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="module">
  <br>
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='modules/OdvetviTechnologie/Automobil.Prumysl.png') }}" width="320" height="200" />
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='modules/OdvetviTechnologie/Zdravotnictvi.png') }}" width="320" height="200" />
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='modules/OdvetviTechnologie/Doprava.png') }}" width="320" height="200" />
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='modules/OdvetviTechnologie/Finance.png') }}" width="320" height="200" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="textBox1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-id="autprumysl"></div>
  <div id="textBox2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-id="zdravotnictvi"></div>
  <div id="textBox3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-id="doprava"></div>
  <div id="textBox4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-id="finance"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="drag">
    <span class="span" id="doprava" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Doprava</span>
    <span class="span" id="zdravotnictvi" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Zdravotnictví</span>
    <span class="span" id="autprumysl" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Automobilový průmysl</span>
    <span class="span" id="finance" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Finance</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p style="font-size:20px; text-align: center;" class="score">0/0</p>
</div>
```

Comment: After the logic corrected. You can either have a text overlap the image or back to your code, create a table where you can drag and drop your text into.

Comment: The text should be dragged into the boxes that are also in the html code that I sent, @StevenXXCCC

Comment: Yes, sorry for the misunderstanding. But, if you using the way I used: to match with the drag element's id with the destination's data-id. it will be more accurate and less redundant code in "drop" function. Please see the updated snippet.

Comment: Adding a score still doesn't work for me, I pinned the example with my question on my contribution. @StevenXXCCC

Comment: The score counting works for me no problem. Please try copy the code down to a editor and watch for errors in console if any. otherwise, watch for the names spelling in Czech. It may be because of that. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, I have already found a mistake and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few mistakes in the code:

1. The event on the items to be dragged should have been ondragstart(ev) so that you can capture what to do when the item starts dragging.
2. You were matching Ids of the items being dragged to the Id of the container where the items are dragged, so they never got inside the if condition.
3. Now, if you want to use indexOf to check if the element is part of an array using their Ids, the Id of the items being dragged (in this case, span) must be exactly same as one of the values in array (cases too).

Here's a working code (also added basic css, so that the text boxes are actually visible):

```js
var score = 0;
var doprava = ['Doprava'];
var zdravotnictvi = ['Zdravotnictví'];
var autprumysl = ['Automobilový průmysl'];
var finance = ['Finance']
var scoreElement = document.querySelector(".score");

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  if (ev.target.id == 'textBox3' && doprava.indexOf(data) != -1) {
    score++;
    scoreElement.innerHTML = score.toString() + "/4";
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
  if (ev.target.id == 'textBox2' && zdravotnictvi.indexOf(data) != -1) {
    score++;
    scoreElement.innerHTML = score.toString() + "/4";
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
  if (ev.target.id == 'textBox4' && finance.indexOf(data) != -1) {
    score++;
    scoreElement.innerHTML = score.toString() + "/4";
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
  if (ev.target.id == 'textBox1' && autprumysl.indexOf(data) != -1) {
    score++;
    scoreElement.innerHTML = score.toString() + "/4";
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
}
```

```css
#textBox1, #textBox2, #textBox3, #textBox4 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="module">
  <br>
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='modules/OdvetviTechnologie/Automobil.Prumysl.png') }}" width="320" height="200" />
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='modules/OdvetviTechnologie/Zdravotnictvi.png') }}" width="320" height="200" />
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='modules/OdvetviTechnologie/Doprava.png') }}" width="320" height="200" />
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='modules/OdvetviTechnologie/Finance.png') }}" width="320" height="200" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="textBox1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="textBox2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="textBox3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="textBox4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="drag">
    <span class="span" id="Doprava" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Doprava</span>
    <span class="span" id="Zdravotnictví" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Zdravotnictví</span>
    <span class="span" id="Automobilový průmysl" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Automobilový průmysl</span>
    <span class="span" id="Finance" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Finance</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p style="font-size:20px; text-align: center;" class="score">0/0</p>
</div>
```